# Login Page is not working.

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having trouble on getting the `MySQL` column. EVERYTHING in mysql is set with the **username, password, database, table**, and the **column**.

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/socialhut/login.php on line 8
```

Here's the code for login.php:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($result==1){
session_register($username);
session_register($password);
header('location:members.php');
}else{
mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Can anyone figure it out?
Thanks!

Comment: your query is failing, use mysql_error(), to see what error are you getting...please update to mysqli o PDO

Comment: 1. SQL injection! 2. `$query` is likely `false` due to an issue with your query or connection. Try `mysql_error()` to see what's going on. 3. Stop using the mysql_* functions! They're deprecated.

Comment: did you allow phpmyadmin to grant this account to get data?

Comment: I did a mix of all of your suggestions and I got it with the help of all of you! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` calls in the same code. You can't do that.

Try this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($query === false) {die(mysqli_error($conn));}
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```